# setLatestEventInfo() can not resolve in Android Studio

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am working in Android Studio and trying to generate notification on Specific date and time. All are going right but, In my Service class setLatestEventInfo() method can not be resolved. 
I have done same demo in eclipse and there is no any issue with eclipse.
I don't want to generate notification on any Button's click or any manual event generation but on specific date and time as I specified.

Code for Service class is as follows :

```
public class MyRemiderService extends Service {
private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    mManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            HomeActivity.class);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg,
            "This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!",
            pendingNotificationIntent);


    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Please, let me provide solution about it.. Thanks.

Comment: Ohhh.. Is there any alternative about it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As see here [setLatestEventInfo](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html) :

*setLatestEventInfo method is removed from Notification class*

To create `Notification` use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) class as:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MyRemiderService.this);
.....
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. notification_template_icon_bg)
       .setContentTitle("ContentTitle")
       .....
       .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg, notification);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. notification_template_icon_bg)
        .setContentTitle("Music player")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg, notification);
```

Comment: please check this for 23+ SDK version